# How to add point to a polyline?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#, line

I have a `polyline`, and i want to add `point (vertex)` on a specific distance, like two meters for example.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [IPolyCurve:SplitAtDistance](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/SplitAtDistance_Method/002m000002m7000000/) Method. This

> Adds a new vertex point to the curve at a specified distance from the
>   From point of the curve.  For a split to happen, the split distance
>   must be between the From and To points of the polycurve.

Just remember to set the *CreatePart* to false. This way the polyline will not be split, but just a new vertex added.